# Creating a VPN connection with Mac

Tags: mac, vpn

I will soon be traveling to a country where many pages are blocked. Therefore, I was thinking to convert my Mac to some sort of a connection point (something like VPN) and connect through it. Is that possible? If so, how to do it?

I'm using OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Sure it's possible… Have you searched for the keywords "OS X" and "VPN server"? Have you tried something already?

Comment: It's possible, but it requires a details tutorial. There are a lot of aspects to this... Getting a DNS, Setting up port forwarding on your router, setting up the VPN endpoint... Choosing the *type* of VPN you want. It's a bit outside the scope of super user.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your own VPN Server using Softether, its OpenSource software, offers strong encryption and also runs behind a NAT/Firewall.

https://www.softether.org

Softether is also able to penetrate firewalls by obfuscating the VPN traffic as SSL(HTTPS) connection. So it is quite effective to get arount government censorhsip systems. Perhaps this is even better than commercial VPN Providers cause many public IPs of commercial VPN providers are blocked in some countries.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to setup a system wide vpn using tailored commercial software.

Just download, setup, input login, and start vpn. Downside is that you have to pay. Most vpn's have easy to understand instructions.

More generalized 'free' versions are slightly harder to setup such as OpenVPN.

It's important to use a vpn provider that you can trust, as snippets of internet activity and info can be picked up at the emerging end of the vpn. Therefore it is wise to review the community standing of the vpn before purchasing it.

Using a free vpn can be more often than not, risky, compared to paid vpn's.

A good reasonably priced, and fast, easy to use, secure vpn which I have used for 1 year is: Private internet access, though I use it on windows.

It is worth mentioning that this VPN provider is not stable on my iPhone and iPad (possibly because they use LT2P protocol), however the client software should be fine on your mac.